# ExactTarget Retieve Email using the REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, rest

I'm able to retrieve the contents of an email using SOAP.

Ex.

```
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
        <TriggeredSendDefinition>
           <CustomerKey>99999</CustomerKey>
        </TriggeredSendDefinition>
        <Subscribers>
           <EmailAddress>a@b.com</EmailAddress>
           <SubscriberKey>a@b.com</SubscriberKey>
           <Attributes>
              <Name>HTML__Body</Name>
              <Value>
              <![CDATA[
              <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
              ]]>
              </Value>  

           </Attributes>

        </Subscribers>
     </Objects>
  </CreateRequest>
```

How can I do this using the REST API. I can't find any documentation on this?

Thanks
-Dan

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/emails/email-retrieve.html) 'Get' is the equivalent REST API. You can use the appropriate REST SDK - Ruby/ Python/ PHP/ C#/ Java to invoke it depending on what language you are using.

e.g. in PHP, you would do something like this

```
require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$email = new ET_Email();
$email->authStub = $myclient;
$response = $email->get();
print_r($response);
```

Comment: How would I do this just making a rest call?

Comment: So I dug into the FUEL SDK for JAVA and it uses a SOAP call to retrieve the emails.  That would be ok but the SDK is out of date.  It's throwing errors because there is a new EmailType called Normal and the code has not been updated in a while.